# Can't uninstall forum module

Tags: 8

my core forum module installation gone wrong on a drupal 8.5.1 system and now, when I want to uninstall it I get:

```
    $ drush pmu --verbose forum
    Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_R3Uhpd --database=drupal_2 --host=localhost --port=3306 --silent  < /tmp/drush_enDNb4
    Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_OWoaeC --database=drupal_2 --host=localhost --port=3306 --silent  < /tmp/drush_3gNq9b
    The following extensions will be uninstalled: forum
    Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
    array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! EntityStorageBase.php:227                                                                                                                    [warning]
    TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\forum\ForumUninstallValidator::hasTermsForVocabulary() must implement interface Drupal\taxonomy\VocabularyInterface, null given, called in                   [error]
    /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/modules/forum/src/ForumUninstallValidator.php on line 61 in Drupal\forum\ForumUninstallValidator->hasTermsForVocabulary() (line 103 of
    /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/modules/forum/src/ForumUninstallValidator.php) 
    #0 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/modules/forum/src/ForumUninstallValidator.php(61): Drupal\forum\ForumUninstallValidator->hasTermsForVocabulary(NULL)
    #1 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php(560): Drupal\forum\ForumUninstallValidator->validate('forum')
    #2 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php(365): Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->validateUninstall(Array)
    #3 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php(91): Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->uninstall(Array, true)
    #4 /vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/drupal/environment.inc(227): Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Extension\ModuleInstaller->uninstall(Array)
    #5 /vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/drupal/pm_8.inc(79): drush_module_uninstall(Array)
    #6 /vendor/drush/drush/commands/pm/pm.drush.inc(1250): _drush_pm_uninstall(Array)
    #7 /vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(422): drush_pm_uninstall('forum')
    #8 /vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
    #9 /vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(199): drush_command('forum')
    #10 /vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch(Array)
    #11 /vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
    #12 /vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(12): drush_main()
    #13 {main}.
    TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\forum\ForumUninstallValidator::hasTermsForVocabulary() must implement interface Drupal\taxonomy\VocabularyInterface, null given, called in /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/modules/forum/src/ForumUninstallValidator.php on line 61 in /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/modules/forum/src/ForumUninstallValidator.php on line 103 #0 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/modules/forum/src/ForumUninstallValidator.php(61): Drupal\forum\ForumUninstallValidator->hasTermsForVocabulary(NULL)
    #1 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php(560): Drupal\forum\ForumUninstallValidator->validate('forum')
    #2 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php(365): Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->validateUninstall(Array)
    #3 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php(91): Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->uninstall(Array, true)
    #4 /vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/drupal/environment.inc(227): Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Extension\ModuleInstaller->uninstall(Array)
    #5 /vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/drupal/pm_8.inc(79): drush_module_uninstall(Array)
    #6 /vendor/drush/drush/commands/pm/pm.drush.inc(1250): _drush_pm_uninstall(Array)
    #7 /vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(422): drush_pm_uninstall('forum')
    #8 /vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
    #9 /vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(199): drush_command('forum')
    #10 /vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch(Array)
    #11 /vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
    #12 /vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(12): drush_main()
    #13 {main}
    TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\forum\ForumUninstallValidator::hasTermsForVocabulary() must implement interface Drupal\taxonomy\VocabularyInterface, null given, called in /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/modules/forum/src/ForumUninstallValidator.php on line 61 in Drupal\forum\ForumUninstallValidator->hasTermsForVocabulary() (line 103 of /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/modules/forum/src/ForumUninstallValidator.php).
    Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                                                                                  [error]
    A non well formed numeric value encountered drush.inc:1671
```

How can I uninstall this module, because this problem leads to crash on the admin/modules/uninstall page:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\forum\ForumUninstallValidator::hasTermsForVocabulary() must implement interface Drupal\taxonomy\VocabularyInterface, null given, called in /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/modules/forum/src/ForumUninstallValidator.php on line 61 in Drupal\forum\ForumUninstallValidator->hasTermsForVocabulary() (line 103 of core/modules/forum/src/ForumUninstallValidator.php).
```

My server config:
Apache/2.4.29 (FreeBSD) OpenSSL/1.0.1u-freebsd PHP/7.1.14

PHP Ver. 7.1.14

DB MySQL Ver. 5.6.37

EDIT:

I forgot to mention, that admin/structure/forum gives me this:

```
Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->loadMultiple() (line 227 of /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php)
#0 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/includes/bootstrap.inc(582): _drupal_error_handler_real(2, 'array_flip(): C...', '/usr/local/www/...', 227, Array) 
#1 [internal function]: _drupal_error_handler(2, 'array_flip(): C...', '/usr/local/www/...', 227, Array) 
#2 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php(227): array_flip(Array) 
#3 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php(212): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->loadMultiple(Array) 
#4 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/modules/forum/src/Form/Overview.php(54): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->load(NULL) 
#5 [internal function]: Drupal\forum\Form\Overview->buildForm(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState), NULL) 
#6 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(514): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
#7 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(271): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->retrieveForm('forum_overview', Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState)) 
#8 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Controller/FormController.php(74): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm('forum_overview', Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState)) 
#9 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatch)) 
#10 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(123): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
#11 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(582): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() 
#12 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(124): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure)) 
#13 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(97): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) 
#14 /usr/local/www/drupal2/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(151): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() 
#15 /usr/local/www/drupal2/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1) 
#16 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(57): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) 
#17 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(47): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) 
#18 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(99): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) 
#19 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(78): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) 
#20 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/modules/ban/src/BanMiddleware.php(50): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) 
#21 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(47): Drupal\ban\BanMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) 
#22 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(50): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) 
#23 /usr/local/www/drupal2/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) 
#24 /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(664): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) 
#25 /usr/local/www/drupal2/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) 
#26 {main}. 

Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->loadMultiple() (line 227 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php). 

Page not found.
```

THX

Comment: My guess would be when you enabled the forum module it created some taxonomy vocabularies and terms and you deleted them manually before doing the uninstall and the uninstall is trying to delete them but they no longer exist

Comment: I did not deleted anything. Like I sad...the web UI instalation of the forum modeule crashed. Then I did a composer/drush based reinstall of the geocoder module and then I found that the crashed forum install is blocking the admin/modules/uninstall feature.

Answer (score 2):

Just re-create Forums vocabulary and then you should be able able to uninstall the module.

Comment: But how to do that? Is there some sql scritp to create the missing vocabulary?

Comment: Please read https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/structure-taxonomy-setup.html to learn how to create taxonomy vocabularies.

Comment: admin/structure/taxonomy/add gives me this:
`Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityMalformedException: The entity does not have an ID. in Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityStorage->save() (line 248 of /usr/local/www/drupal2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Entity/ConfigEntityStorage.php).`

Answer (score 1):

You can temporally edit **core/modules/forum/src/ForumUninstallValidator.php** like that:

```
  /**
   * Determines if there are any taxonomy terms for a specified vocabulary.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\taxonomy\VocabularyInterface $vocabulary
   *   The vocabulary to check for terms.
   *
   * @return bool
   *   TRUE if there are terms for this vocabulary, FALSE otherwise.
   */
  protected function hasTermsForVocabulary(VocabularyInterface $vocabulary = NULL) {
    return FALSE;
    $terms = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->getQuery()
      ->condition('vid', $vocabulary->id())
      ->accessCheck(FALSE)
      ->range(0, 1)
      ->execute();
    return !empty($terms);
  }
```

This way you will be able to uninstall the module. Then don't forget to rollback your changes!

Answer (score 1):

The following fixed it and I suspect it's because of some bug in the Devel module (in my case) when generating Forum contents without having a Forums vocabulary :

1. Created a "Forums" vocabulary at  **/admin/structure/taxonomy/add**
2. Going back to **/admin/modules/uninstall** no more error but the Forum checkbox is disabled and has this message :

> ```
> The following reason prevents Forum from being uninstalled:
>
> To uninstall Forum, first delete all Forum content
> ```

3. At content admin **admin/content?title=&type=forum&status=All&langcode=All** delete all forum type content. (I had it generated by the Devel module).
4. Now going back to Modules > Uninstall  the forum checkbox is enabled and uninstallable.

Comment: This exact step fixed my issue.  BUT,,, I used drush for uninstalling this instead of the Extend -> Uninstall Module Route

Answer (score 0):

try checking your db first:

`select * from public.node__taxonomy_forums`

`select * from public.taxonomy_term_revision__forum_container;`

I found 3 terms in taxonomy_term_revision__forum_container that I did not know about. Once these were deleted I was able to successfully uninstall Forum.

`drush pmu forum`